# Is using IP sockets for RPC functionality for a distributed system a good idea?

Tags: php, sockets, daemon, rpc, json-rpc

I am curious if using an socket daemon in PHP a good idea for building RPC functionality on a distributed system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on what exactly you're doing.  But in general, I'd personally build a restful interface as opposed to using raw sockets.  That way it's just a normal HTTP get (which is easy to use, extend, etc) rather than needing to invent your own protocol.  Either that, or use one of the many RPC protocols:

- XMLRPC
- JSONRPC <- I like this since it's so easy to use in just about any language
- SOAP
- etc...